# fopen not opening File

Tags: c, string, stdin, fopen

I'm pretty sure this is the way to open a file:

```
int readFile(char *filename){
char *source = NULL;
int fileSize;
char nameFile[strlen(filename)];
strcpy(nameFile,filename);
puts(nameFile);//Check if the string is correct
FILE *fp;

if ((fp =fopen(nameFile, "r")) != NULL) {
    /* Go to the end of the file. */
    if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
        /* Get the size of the file. */
        long bufsize = ftell(fp);
        if (bufsize == -1) { /* Error */ }

        /* Allocate our buffer to that size. */
        source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));
        fileSize = (sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));

        /* Go back to the start of the file. */
        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { /* Error */ }

        /* Read the entire file into memory. */
        size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), bufsize, fp);
        if (newLen == 0) {
            fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
        } else {
            source[++newLen] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
} else{
    printf("File Doesnt Exist. :( \n");
    return 0;
}
```

So, Im in my working directory. When I compile, the executable is created where the file is. I've done a puts to compare the name of the file. The filename(as to what is shown in the terminal is the same);
I switched the "r" to "r+" and I still got to my File doesn't exist.
Also, I made fopen("actualFileName.txt") and it did work...so...any ideas??

This is how I call readFile:

```
fgets(userInput,sizeof(userInput),stdin);
readFile(userInput);
```

Comment: have you tried `char nameFile[strlen(filename)+1];` and `nameFile[strlen(filename)]='\0'` ? Smells like a missing closer to me!

Comment: why make a copy of the file name anyway

Comment: @pm100 You are right that there is no need to copy filename in the first place.  He was probably trying to debug why the fopen was failing

Comment: the use of perror as suggested below will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
char nameFile[strlen(filename)];
```

it should be

```
char nameFile[1 + strlen(filename)];
```

because `strlen()` doesn't include the terminating `nul` byte, still your code is very dangerous because `filename` could be `NULL`, in that case since you never check for that then undefined behavior will happen when calling `strlen()`.

This

```
source[++newLen] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
```

is evidence that you know that strings require a `'\0'` at the end.

So you are allocating less memory than needed and hence the problem, BTW `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

When you try to check the file name by outputting, do it this way

```
printf("*%s*\n", nameFile);
```

that way if the output is, for example

```
*this_is_the_filename.txt
*
```

It means that the `'\n'` read by `fgets()` is still in the buffer, so you need to delete it, when using `fgets()` you can do this

```
size_t length;

fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);

length = strlen(userInput);
if (userInput[userInput - 1] == '\n')
    userInput[userInput - 1] = '\0';
```

to avoid having the `'\n'` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

One issue:

```
char nameFile[strlen(filename)];
```

should be:

```
char nameFile[strlen(filename) + 1];
```

Another potential issue:

```
fgets(userInput,sizeof(userInput),stdin);
```

Leaves any line termination embedded at the end of userInput (e.g. - "\n" on *nix, "\r\n" on Windows).  That may be why you can't open your file.  Try:

```
if (NULL == fgets(userInput,sizeof(userInput),stdin)) { /* handle error */ }
for (i = strlen(userInput); i > 0 && isspace(userInput[i]); --i);
userInput[i] = '\0';
readFile(userInput);
```

Also, you might get more information on why fopen is failing from:

```
perror("File Doesnt Exist. :( \n");
```

Comment: In c it will always be `'\n'` only windows applications add the `'\r\n'` to terminate lines.